# I merged two conflicted branches. Now git status doesn't show any changes

Tags: git, merge

Ay carumba. Fairly new to Git. I merged my master branch with a "test" branch. There were conflicts. I modified the test branch files by hand so there were no longer any conflicts, and committed them. I was able to merge. Congratulations all around.

Now, however, when I make any changes to the master branch, and check git status, I get:

```
On branch master
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'.
```

`git diff` and `git diff HEAD` show nothing.

`git diff HEAD^` shows me older changes I don't recognize from the merge.

And for added fun, if I do git branch, I see master, but my "test" branch is gone! (I didn't delete it).

The changes I've made since the merge are minor, and I would be happy to revert and lose those changes, as long as my master would recognize changes again!

Is `git reset HEAD --hard` the answer?

I'm reading through documentation and Stack Overflow and see a lot of things that are *close* to what I need, but at this point I'm too scared to try anything...

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Can you add the relevant part of `git log --graph --decorate --all --oneline`?

Comment: When you merged, were you on the master branch and ran a command like: "git merge test"? If so, and if you did not already push, then "git status" should not say "your branch is up-to-date with origin/master"

Answer (score 0):

Use `git reflog` to inspect your recent activity, you can get your `test` branch back and retry the merge.

Answer (score 0):

OK, that was weird...quit terminal, quit Sublime, quit my browsers, did NOT reboot my machine. Came back today, git status showed the four files that changed. Git diff showed the minor changes in those files. I committed and pushed them, then made another minor change just to see if it was working again...and it was. Ok...it's stuff like this that scares me...